# How we do the Mixed ANOVA post comparison

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, post-hoc, clinical-trials

I am learning and doing the Mixed ANOVA using Python pingouin under a clinical example dataset that contains one between factor (drug: A, B, C) and one within factor (Time: T0, T1, T2, T3, T4) from 5 subjects interested in the weight reduction.

What I am interested in:

1. significance between (T0 vs T1, T0 vs T2, T0 vs T3, T0 vs T4) for each drug.
2. significance between (A vs B, A vs C, B vs C) on each timepoint

first, I did the Mixed Anova:
`pg.mixed_anova(data=data, dv='weight', between='drug', within='Time', subject='subject')`

according to the results, drug, Time, and interaction are significant.

[image: mixed Anova result]

Second, I would like to do the multi-comparison.
`pg.pairwise_tests(data=data, dv='weight', between='drug', within='Time', subject='subject', effsize='eta-square', return_desc=True, padjust='sidak').round(4)`

the output provides Time and drug main comparison (**is this important under the significant interaction?**) and provides all pairwise comparisons of drugs on each time point (**are these comparisons correct? Are these True that I could conduct, for example, A is better than B at T2? what if drugs are sig different at T0**). (**however, it didn't give me the pairwise comparisons of time points on each drug, how can I have these information?**)

so, this makes me confused about two different comparisons (see below) (**which one should I use?**):

first way: compare drugs at each time point without considering if drugs at T0 are different (`pg.pairwise_tests`)
[image: weight as function of time point]

second way: I made the minus (T1-T0, T2-T0, T3-T0, T4-T0) to see their delta values. then, I used multiple comparisons of drugs at each time point (with p-value correction)

[image: Delta value, weight as function of time point]

anyway, the ultimate objectives are to access the efficacy of each drug over time and efficacy comparison of drugs at each time point to find the best drug.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your question is no more complicated than adjusting for time and drug as a *categorical* variable rather than a continuous variable. You might consider an ANOVA contrast for the effect of DRUG.

The line and error bar plot is useful because we can see the effects appear quite heterogeneous, i.e. response does not increase linearly with time, nor are the treatment-specific curves parallel to each other.